# When appending to my file, it isnt spacing correctly

Tags: python, file, file-io

The issue has been annoying me for a while now, I'm not sure how to explain. There is more info in the code itself, have a look. (info is on the hashtags on lines 22 onward.)

```
myFile = open ("C38test.txt","wt")
myFile.write(input("Enter numbers to put in a list, leave a space between each number.:\n"))
myFile.close()

myFile = open("C38test.txt","rt")
contents = myFile.read()
user_list = contents.split() #Note to self: "split()" splits by whitespace.
for i in range(len(user_list)):
    user_list[i] = int(user_list[i])
mean = sum(user_list)/len(user_list)
total = sum(user_list)
print("Sum = ", total)
print("Mean = ", mean)
myFile.close()

cont = input("Do you want to add any more numbers? Answer with Yes or No:\n") 
n = int(input("How many numbers do you want to add?:\n"))
if cont == ("Yes") or ("yes"):                                                
    myFile = open("C38test.txt","at")
for a in range (n):                                 #Lines 22-24 is where I believe the issue is (I could be wrong but this seems most likely). 
    newNo = input("Please enter new number/s:\n")     #It is not automatically putting a space between the numbers when you enter them.
    myFile.write(str(newNo))                        #The issue with this is that the numbers arent entered at the same time. And it doesn't space them from the original integers either.
myFile.close()
myFile = open("C38test.txt","rt")
contents2 = myFile.read()
user_list2 = contents2.split()
for q in range(len(user_list2)):
    user_list2[q] = int(user_list2[q])
mean2 = sum(user_list2)/len(user_list2)
total2 = sum(user_list2)
print("Sum = ",total2)
print("Mean = ",mean2)
```

Comment: "I'm not sure how to explain" You could start by telling us: 1. How should the program be run (i.e., what should the text file contain, in order to reproduce the problem; what other input is needed)? 2. What should happen when the program runs (exactly what output should you see displayed, what should the file contain afterward, etc.)? 3. What actually does happen? 4. How is that different?

Comment: That said: yes, `.write` will only write the things you tell it to write. You did not tell it to write any space between the numbers, so it doesn't. As a side note: `if cont == ("Yes") or ("yes"):` does not mean what you presumably intend (and also the parentheses have no effect here).

Comment: This part of the program is meant to ask the user for a list of numbers, these numbers are stored in a text file. The program then prints the sum and mean of these numbers. This all works fine. Then after that the program is going to run an if statement (not completed yet i want to get this part working first) in which it asks them if they want to add more numbers to the file. However, when they say yes and add the numbers, the file does not automatically put a space between the numbers. For eg. if i had "10 20 30" in the file, and the user adds a 20, the file will store it as "10 20 3020"

Comment: Therefore it will add the numbers up incorrectly. I want to find a way for a space to be added between these numbers without the user having to manually input a space.

Comment: Did you try explicitly writing a space into the file?

Comment: What do you mean? Apologies im not the most experienced programmer so things are gonna need a bit more explaining, however i have tried a few different ways of solving this issue, nothing has worked so far.

Comment: When you put `myFile.write(...)`, the `...` part says what you will write into the file, correct? Did you try using a string that has a space in it for that part? For example, `' '`? Do you see how that would help with the problem of adding a space between the other things you are writing to the file?

Comment: Tried this yesterday, I changed line 24 to this,`myFile.write(' '+newNo)` the effect it has was the following. It made the code work if you are only appending one number, however, any more than this and it does not work. It also breaks the FOR loop it is a part of. What i found is that when you added a number that is the same as one of the original numbers entered, it will not write it to the file.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand from that description either what the new code looks like, what the resulting output looks like, or how the resulting output is different from desired. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You should show us **exactly** what is contained in `C38test.txt` before and after (using a simple example for the initial contents), except formatted as code.

Comment: I dont see why I need to do that as the issue has not changed from the beginning. The only thing that changed is the system in which it does read and write from the file. So there isn't really a new output or file contents. I also provided simple examples earlier on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to add a line break after each new number. You have a line break character in the input string, but that is for the display that the user sees. You need to add a line break char to the string that you write to the file.
So you would change lines 22-24 to:

```
for a in range (n):                          
    newNo = input("Please enter value: ")
    myFile.write(newNo + '\n')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this and it didn't work. The line break in the user string is intentional just to make things a bit neater.

Comment: When you tried this, what happened? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Nothing did, the program still ran with the usual issue, and the inputted numbers were stored on the same line still.